# Not able to call REST service with a file parameter, Getting error Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?"

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-rest

Below is Client Class, This class contains REST client which calling a REST service with File parameter:

```
package com.main;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
// Service Class with REST Client
public class ServiceCaller {
//main method contains service REST Client
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 //creating multivaluemap object
  MultiValueMap<String, Object> bodyMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
  bodyMap.add("file", "F:\\DelhiAirportDemo.txt");
  //creating headers
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
  //creating entity with bodymap and header
  HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyMap, headers);

  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  //below calling service exposed on local host
  ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/Bandwidth_Evaluation_Server/upload",
          HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
  System.out.println("response status: " + response.getStatusCode());
  System.out.println("response body: " + response.getBody());
  }

}
```

Below is my dispatcher-servlet.xml, which has multipartResolver configuration in it.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    //component scan to scan all the controllers
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
    // view resolver bean is configured
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    //configuring content negotiation manager
    <bean id="cnManager"
        class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
        <property name="useJaf" value="false" />
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <!-- <entry key="html" value="text/html" /> -->
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    //configuring multipartResolver bean for multipart file
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20000000" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Below is my Server Controller Class:

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
// spring controller class with a service exposed here
@Controller
public class UploadController {

     // This method will be called from client main method
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    //checking file is empty or not
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Please select a file to upload");
            return "redirect:uploadStatus";
        }
        try {
            // Get the file and save it somewhere
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
            // writing file
            Files.write(path, bytes);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");

        } catch (IOException e) {
//catching exceptions here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "redirect:/uploadStatus";
    }
}
```

Below is the error getting on client side

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal
>   Server Error

Below is the error getting on server side

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected
>   MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve This will help you createa a question, that more people are willing to answer.

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace of both server and client